# What do these gates mean in veins?

Tags: veins

Some of the codes in veins are as follows:

```
int upperLayerIn;
int upperLayerOut;
int lowerLayerIn;
int lowerLayerOut;
int upperControlIn;
int upperControlOut;
int lowerControlIn;
int lowerControlOut;
```

I want to know what these gates mean? MAC? Application layer?

Answer (score 0):

As of Veins 5.0, these gates are used by every layer to communicate with the layer above/below for sending/receiving data/control messages (hence, the 2x2x2=8 gates).

One example is the `PHY layer` telling the `MAC layer` via a `control message` that it has finished transmitting a frame. This would go the route of `phy.upperControlOut -> mac.lowerControlIn`.